# Databinding a WPF grid control to a CSV file

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, csv, .net-4.5

Is something like this possible?

I'm currently trying to read a CSV file directly into a WPF DataGrid.  The file doesn't have a known format - that is, I don't know what the field are, or how many there are.  I just want to display to entire file in a grid format (in a similar way to what excel does when you open a CSV file).

Comment: Will you always have a header row?

Comment: I can have if that provides a solution

Comment: It's more csv-read/write issue. As soon as you'll have parsing functionality it would be much easier to implement paging and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not immediately familiar with the WPF variant of the DataGrid, but with the general .NET  DataGrid and DataGridView controls. Assuming that this control operates in a similar fashion, you need only open the csv file, loop through it reading line by line and splitting on either tabs or commas, and throwing the data into a DataTable. From there, you can set the DataSource of the DataGrid control to the DataTable (or create a DataView, if you need some custom formatting / viewing), and call the Refresh() method.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid is based on the [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) control, and items are represented by [ItemsControl.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) whioch type is `IEnumerable`. So if you simply want to display CSV in a DataGrid you should read CSV in any data structure which implements `IEnumerable` and set it to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property through the code behing on more preferrable way  -binding from the XAML. So your grid would have a single column which represent an entire CSV file line. If you want to show each value in a separate column - each item of `IEnumerable` data structure (I would suggest `IList<>`) should represent `IEnumerable` as well, basically `IList<IEnumerable<object>>`.

To read CSV in the local data structure I would suggest using some free CSV parsing library rather than doing this yourself since parsing of the CSV sometimes tricky thing. Take a look at the [KBCsv library](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/) as a case.

I believe this is pretty close example of what you are trying to do:
[Binding a ListView to a Data Matrix](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DynamicListView.aspx)
(*ListView is the ItemsControl as well so solution woudl be the same*)